# How can I get client PC Printer settings using C#, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reporting-services, printing

I have SSRS report runnig on a web application. I want to print SSRS report data directly on the client's printer. The application works well in my pc but when I publish the application on IIS web server, instead of retrieving the printer settings of client pc, the application is trying to look for printers that are installed in the server machine.

I am using System.Drawing.Printing, Is there any way to get the settings of installed printer in the client computer or can we print SSRS reports from Web using C# ?

I am using following code.

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;
    using System.Drawing.Printing;
    using System.Collections.Specialized;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;
    using SeaWorld.Common.Helper;

namespace SeaWorld.BusinessObjects.BAL.Generated
{
    public class ReportPrintDocument : PrintDocument
    {
        private PageSettings m_pageSettings;
        private int m_currentPage;
        private List<Stream> m_pages = new List<Stream>();

        public ReportPrintDocument(ServerReport serverReport): this((Report)serverReport)
        {
            RenderAllServerReportPages(serverReport);
        }

        //public ReportPrintDocument(LocalReport localReport): this((Report)localReport)
        //{
        //    RenderAllLocalReportPages(localReport);
        //}

        private ReportPrintDocument(Report report)
        {
            // Set the page settings to the default defined in the report
            ReportPageSettings reportPageSettings = report.GetDefaultPageSettings();

            // The page settings object will use the default printer unless
            // PageSettings.PrinterSettings is changed.  This assumes there
            // is a default printer.
            m_pageSettings = new PageSettings();
            m_pageSettings.PaperSize = reportPageSettings.PaperSize;
            m_pageSettings.Margins = reportPageSettings.Margins;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);

            if (disposing)
            {
                foreach (Stream s in m_pages)
                {
                    s.Dispose();
                }

                m_pages.Clear();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnBeginPrint(PrintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnBeginPrint(e);

            m_currentPage = 0;
        }

        protected override void OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPrintPage(e);

            Stream pageToPrint = m_pages[m_currentPage];
            pageToPrint.Position = 0;

            // Load each page into a Metafile to draw it.
            using (Metafile pageMetaFile = new Metafile(pageToPrint))
            {
                Rectangle adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
                        e.PageBounds.Left - (int)e.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
                        e.PageBounds.Top - (int)e.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
                        e.PageBounds.Width,
                        e.PageBounds.Height);

                // Draw a white background for the report
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);

                // Draw the report content
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(pageMetaFile, adjustedRect);

                // Prepare for next page.  Make sure we haven't hit the end.
                m_currentPage++;
                e.HasMorePages = m_currentPage < m_pages.Count;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnQueryPageSettings(QueryPageSettingsEventArgs e)
        {
            e.PageSettings = (PageSettings)m_pageSettings.Clone();
        }

        private void RenderAllServerReportPages(ServerReport serverReport)
        {
            string deviceInfo = CreateEMFDeviceInfo();

            // Generating Image renderer pages one at a time can be expensive.  In order
            // to generate page 2, the server would need to recalculate page 1 and throw it
            // away.  Using PersistStreams causes the server to generate all the pages in
            // the background but return as soon as page 1 is complete.
            NameValueCollection firstPageParameters = new NameValueCollection();
            firstPageParameters.Add("rs:PersistStreams", "True");

            // GetNextStream returns the next page in the sequence from the background process
            // started by PersistStreams.
            NameValueCollection nonFirstPageParameters = new NameValueCollection();
            nonFirstPageParameters.Add("rs:GetNextStream", "True");

            string mimeType;
            string fileExtension;
            Stream pageStream = serverReport.Render("IMAGE", deviceInfo, firstPageParameters, out mimeType, out fileExtension);

            // The server returns an empty stream when moving beyond the last page.
            while (pageStream.Length > 0)
            {
                m_pages.Add(pageStream);

                pageStream = serverReport.Render("IMAGE", deviceInfo, nonFirstPageParameters, out mimeType, out fileExtension);
            }
        }

        private void RenderAllLocalReportPages(LocalReport localReport)
        {
            string deviceInfo = CreateEMFDeviceInfo();

            Warning[] warnings;
            localReport.Render("IMAGE", deviceInfo, LocalReportCreateStreamCallback, out warnings);
        }

        private Stream LocalReportCreateStreamCallback(
            string name,
            string extension,
            Encoding encoding,
            string mimeType,
            bool willSeek)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            m_pages.Add(stream);

            return stream;
        }

        private string CreateEMFDeviceInfo()
        {
            PaperSize paperSize = m_pageSettings.PaperSize;
            Margins margins = m_pageSettings.Margins;

            // The device info string defines the page range to print as well as the size of the page.
            // A start and end page of 0 means generate all pages.
            return string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>emf</OutputFormat><StartPage>0</StartPage><EndPage>0</EndPage><MarginTop>{0}</MarginTop><MarginLeft>{1}</MarginLeft><MarginRight>{2}</MarginRight><MarginBottom>{3}</MarginBottom><PageHeight>{4}</PageHeight><PageWidth>{5}</PageWidth></DeviceInfo>",
                ToInches(margins.Top),
                ToInches(margins.Left),
                ToInches(margins.Right),
                ToInches(margins.Bottom),
                ToInches(paperSize.Height),
                ToInches(paperSize.Width));
        }

        private static string ToInches(int hundrethsOfInch)
        {
            double inches = hundrethsOfInch / 100.0;
            return inches.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "in";
        }
    }
}



On print button click

 void ctrlSettingToolbar_btnPrintPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ReportPrintDocument rp = new ReportPrintDocument(rptBillOfLoadings.ServerReport);

                rp.Print();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                LogHelper.PrintError("Error:", ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: System.Drawing.Printing will give the list of printers where the application is hosted..to achieve ur requirement u have to depend some scripting i guess..correct me if I am wrong

Comment: you are right @Sachu that System.Drawing.Printing Only give me the list of printers where the application is hosted or running ... if you have any java script to solve the issue please share with me.

Comment: try below answer..hope it work

Comment: Imagine, for a second, what the world would be like if any website you visited could enumerate your printers and start printing off whatever they wanted to. And I thought pop-ups were annoying.

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript function window.Print()
This will list you client machine printers and print your page.

Hope below code will help..try

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function page()
  {
  window.print()
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Print page" onclick="page()">

</body>
</html>
```

But this will print the whole page..in your case its a report to print

hope this link can guide you

[print crystal report to client printer](http://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-Directly-Print-Crystal-Reports-to-Default-Client-Printer-from-ASP-NET-without-Preview-or-Printer-Dialog/)

[print report to client default printer](http://forums.asp.net/t/1074317.aspx?Sending%20print%20directly%20to%20the%20client%20printer%20without%20showing%20print%20dialog%20in%20crystal%20reports)

Comment: I think this will print the whole screen of window, while I wanted to print only the report visible in the page of report viewer..